# Convert placeholders such as %1$s to {x} in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm parsing an XML doc (using `XMLParser`) and some of the values have php-like placeholders, e.g. `%1$s`, and I would like to convert those to `{x-1}`.

Examples:

**%1$s** ---> **{0}**

**%2$s** ---> **{1}**

I'm doing this in a seemingly hacky way, using regex:

But there must be a better implementation of this regex.

Consider a string:

```
let str = "lala fawesfgeksgjesk 3rf3f %1$s rk32mrk3mfa %2$s fafafczcxz %3$s czcz $#$#@%#@ %4$s qqq %5$s"
```

Now we're going to extract the integer strings between strings **%** and **$s**:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=%)[^$s]+")

let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)

let matches = regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: range)
matches.map {
    print(String(str[Range($0.range, in: str)!]))
}
```

Works quite fine. The issue is that the "4" value got mixed up because of the preceding random strings before the **%4$s**.

Prints:

```
1
2
3
#@ %4
5
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be a very efficient (or swifty :)) way but it gets the job done. What it does is that it searches for a given reg ex and uses the matched substring to extract the numeric value and decrease it and then perform a simple replace between the substring and a newly constructed placeholder value. This is executed in a loop until no more matches are found.

```
let pattern = #"%(\d*)\$s"#

while let range = str.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    let placeholder = str[range]
    let number = placeholder.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)

    if let value = Int(number) {
        str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: placeholder, with: "{\(value - 1)}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was about to stick with my implementation, but this is just better. Thanks.

Comment: Optional binding works in a while-loop: `while let range = str.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) { ... }`